# ionic InAppBrowser not firing event

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Please help someone, below code opening page but not firing event

```
this._browser = this.inAppBrowser.create('http://www.google.com');
    this._browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((event) => {
       let alert1 = this._alertCtrl.create({
        subTitle: 'load start',
        buttons: ['ok!']
      });
      alert1.present();
    });
```

Comment: Can you please share your full code of the ts file?

Comment: Which event is not firing? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Very similar issue for me: I am making an ionic app where I need to call to a website(not exist). I am just trying to catch that into the error. But the "exit" event does not get fired.

    `        this.browser = this.iab.create("http://www.randomwebsite.com/", "_blank", this.options);
        this.browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
            console.log("exit -->", event);
        }, err => {
            console.log("InAppBrowser exit Event Error: " + err);
        }); `